# Netbeans: Using "Step Filters" with Vaadin applications and "*$$$*" classes

Tags: debugging, jakarta-ee, vaadin, netbeans-8

I have Netbeans 8.2 here and I'm trying to debug a Vaadin application on wildfly. Every time I want to do a "step into" from a Vaadin view class method into a Bean (means: every time I step into the JEE container) I must step through several classes of JEE and Vaadin. With the "Step Filter" of NetBeans I can "overstep" these classes. For the most classes this works. But Vaadin (or JEE?) generates some classes like `my.project.LoginBean$$$view23.login`. The question is how can I configure the NetBeans "Step Filter" so that the debugger don't stops in these classes with `$$$` in the name but stops in all other classes of the package (`my.project.` in sample above) while doing a "Step Into". I have tried several "classes matching" defines like

- `*$view*`
- `*Bean$*`
- `*$$$*`
- `*\$\$\$*`

but all without success. In all cases the debugger stops in the "$$$" class.